# iOS 10: Forward user’s iMessage to server and then have it receive a response from a server (Automated Bot)

Tags: objective-c, ios10, imessage

Forward user’s iMessage to server and then have the iMessage receive a response from a server. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but no, it's not possible. The reason is because you cannot access messages once they are on the conversation. More precisely :

- Messages that were not create by your app are just not accessible.
- Messages that were create by your app can be access when : your app is open and a message sent with your app by the other user is received, or the user selects one of the messages sent via your app.

Also, you message app won't be able to automatically send messages, the user will always have to tap the "send" blue button.

So the kind of app you want to dev is in my opinion not possible :/

EDIT :
Have a look here for more clarifications :
https://developer.apple.com/reference/messages/msmessage

And more precisely that part :

> iOS device with the iMessage app installed.
>
> If the extension is not running, the system launches it using the
>   init(session:) presentation style. The conversation’s selectedMessage
>   property is set to the tapped message, and the view controller’s
>   willBecomeActive(with:) and didBecomeActive(with:) methods are called.
>
> If the extension is running, the system calls the view controller’s
>   willSelect(*:conversation:) method. It then updates the conversation’s
>   selectedMessage property and calls the view controller’s
>   didSelect(*:conversation:) method.
>
> Override willSelect(*:conversation:) or didSelect(*:conversation:) to
>   respond to the user selecting a new message.
>
> You can also save messages to the file system and process them later.

Comment: "Messages that were create by your app can be access when : your app is open and a message sent with your app by the other user is received, or the user selects one of the messages sent via your app". Can you explain this?

Comment: Yep sure. 

--- When a user is using your iMessage app, `didReceive(MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation)` will be trigger automatically when a iMessage come (which were send via your app, if it comes from another iMessage app, or is just a simple message, nothing will happen). At that point you'll be able to access/read the message.

--- Finally, if the user tap one a precedent iMessage that were send with your iMessage app, this will open your iMessage app, and then trigger `willSelect(MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation)`